# Business Intelligence - SSDT for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

I was searching for Business Intelligence SSDT tools on Visual Studio 2013.

I found SSDT for Visual Studio 2012 here,

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Can we install the same to install for VS 2013?

If not where can i find SSDT for VS 2013?

Comment: Download setup files: https://ssdt.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11):

It was just released here for Visual Studio 2013: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: After I installed this, why it also installed Visual Studio 2012 for me? That disapointed me.

Comment: Actually it is Visual Studio 2013 Shell. In the above link check the Additional Information section, it is clearly mentioned there.

Comment: Where is it? That link results in "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."

Comment: I have successfully downloaded it on Apr 14 from the above link, but today it redirects to a text file with a message "SSDT-BI has been temporarily removed to deal with side by side issues with SSDT-SQL. We expect to have it reposted soon"

Comment: Updated today, it seems we won't see it for some time... : "The release of SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013 & SQL Server 2014 will take a few more days. We apologize for the inconvenience. In the meantime, you can work on BI projects for SQL Server 2014 using the CTP2 version of SSDT-BI with Visual Studio 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40736."

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2013 support for SSDT [isn't released yet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4096d5ba-67fd-4d83-ab3b-d311edf9afd1/visual-studio-2013-support-for-ssdt-and-ssdtbi?forum=sqlintegrationservices). [The appropriate feedback](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/806079/ssdt-bi-add-visual-studio-2013-support-to-sql-server-data-tools-for-business-intelligence) at connect states that

> SSDT-BI 2014 for Visual Studio 2013 is coming, but not yet available (release date hasn’t been announced yet)

With the release of SQL Server 2014 (seems to be in April) support for Visual Studio 2013 [should be added](http://www.mattmasson.com/2013/10/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-downloads/).

Answer (score 6):

This was released a few days ago (SSDT-BI for VS2013).

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it was promptly removed

Answer (score 5):

The download was not available on April 16th 2014.  The download site "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313" directs to a single text file indicating that SSDT-BI has been temporarily removed .... etc.

Comment: Anyone know what SSDT-SQL is?

Comment: @alphadogg I've been wondering what that is, too.  SSDT-SQL = SQL Server Data Tools SQL..? It seems like the wording they use to describe the problem has been copied and pasted everywhere: their blog, the download page, the download .txt file you get, etc.

Comment: SSDT-SQL is referring to the Database Projects, which you would download as just "SSDT" or were installed with Visual Studio (2013 especially). SSDT-BI is an additional portion for Reporting / Analysis / Integration Services only, which you either downloaded as "SSDT-BI" or was installed by the SQL Server 2012 CD but called "SSDT". The SQL Server 2014 CD doesn't install it at all.

Comment: [USE, FOLLOW, SHARE New Business Intelligence Proposal at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 3):

"**For Visual Studio 2013, there are two different products that are called "SSDT".**

One SSDT includes tools for relational databases in Visual Studio, with features like Data Compare, Schema Compare and SQL Server Database Projects. The other SSDT, referred to as SSDT-BI, includes the BI project types for SSRS, SSIS and SSAS. The SSDT relational tools are included in Visual Studio's setup experience as a checkbox option, but the SSDT-BI tools, on the other hand, are only available as a separate download. This "two SSDTs" thing caused a lot of confusion and was widely regarded as a bad move, so for Visual Studio 2015 we've made some changes." -- [MSDN: How to install SSDT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb2c8b4a-6766-47d6-a459-58ef35566b94/how-to-install-ssdt?forum=ssdt)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server tooling in Visual Studio 2013 - all the great database tools, now acquisition and updates are fully integrated in Express for Web, Express for Windows Desktop, Professional, Premium, and Ultimate. Since SQL Server tooling is included in VS, the updates will be pushed through VS Update and users will be prompted when VS is open. If you'd like to check for updates manually, **open Visual Studio 2013 and choose the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu. SQL Server tooling updates will appear in the Updates list**.

[image]

Comment: I don't see ssdt in that list. Please link to the actual package on the gallery if it does exist. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=ssdt&f%5B0%5D.Value=ssdt&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4

Comment: When you click the Update button it actually opens a browser pointing to http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/4/EE429DFD-563B-4CC7-BF9F-EF9449818192/EN/SSDTSetup.exe

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to upgrade your SQL Server to 2014 before making this jump. It'll upgrade your packages and make them un-usable in SQL Server 2012 environment. I've had to roll my packages back...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2014/04/03/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2013-ssdt-bi.aspx